# Media queries affecting desktop

Tags: css

I have got media queries set up for max-width 812px for a particular div but for some reason this is affecting desktop.

I have tried to change media queries to " media only screen". I have also deleted browser history, cache and cookies as this might have some interference.

CSS desktop code

```
.contact-footer{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 30px;
  background:#90634b;
  color:white;
  bottom:0;
}
```

CSS media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {

.contact-footer{
padding-bottom: 150px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
width:315px;
}

}
```

What is doing is that is cutting the background in half ( which should really but in mobile version not desktop but also doing this in desktop).

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to set width in desktop mode css I.e100%;

Comment: @DimitriosDouras tried to set width:100% and width:800px cause sometimes px stick better but no change

Answer (score -1):

FYI have resolved it.

CSS media queries code needed to be first and then desktop css in the css file.